# Spring-data-jpa lazy loading in @Scheduled and @Transactional methods

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Configuration class I need to run a method as a cronjob. So I created a method by using the `@Scheduled` annotation.

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 10 * 1000, fixedRate = 1000 * 1000)
public void ThemeUpdate() {
    List<ThemeIndex> indices = getServices();
    ...
}
```

The `ThemeUpdate()` method is now running in its own thread and I will lose my transaction. So I created another method by using the `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Transactional
public List<ThemeIndex> getServices() {
    List<Service> services = serviceRepository.findServices();

    Section section = services.get(0).getSections().iterator().next();

    return null;
}
```

I get my `List<Service> services` from my `serviceRepository`. But if I want to access a `Section` which is an `Entity` fetched by lazy loading why do I get a `LazyInitializationException`?

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.myPorject.db.model.Service.sections, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

What do I miss here?

**EDIT:**

Scheduled:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 10 * 1000, fixedRate = 10000 * 1000)
@Transactional
public void ThemeUpdate() {
    List<ThemeIndex> indices = themeUpdateServiceImpl.getIndices();
}
```

getIndices():

```
@Override
public List<ThemeIndex> getIndices() {
    return getIndices(serviceRepository
        .findServices());
}

@Override
public List<ThemeIndex> getIndices(List<Service> services) {
    return themeIndexServiceImpl.getThemeIndexes(services);
}
```

getThemeIndexes():

```
@Override
public List<ThemeIndex> getThemeIndexes(List<Service> services) {
    List<ThemeIndex> themeIndexs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Service s : services) {
        ThemeIndex themeIndex = getThemeIndex(s);
        if (themeIndex != null) {
            themeIndexs.add(themeIndex);
        }
    }
    return themeIndexs;
}

@Override
public ThemeIndex getThemeIndex(Service service) {
    //SQL which is slow
    if (serviceRepository.isEpisService(service.getSvno())) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are locally calling getServices() so there is no transaction proxy for the local method call.

You should move your scheduled method in its own component and inject the component with the getServices() method.

Comment: Thanks its working now. But the selects are 50 times slower than the normal proecessing without `@Schedule` and `@Transactional`. Any reason for that?

Comment: Have you had a look at the SQL statements that are executed by Hibernate? And if you are only selecting data you could try to set the transaction to @Transactional( readOnly = true )

Comment: The statement should be finished in ms. I can try to set the stuff readOnly. But it seems that the transaction is created after every loop. I edited my question to show the current way.

Comment: By the way. The readOnly flag makes the different. Took just 5 seconds instead of 20 minutes ^^. Why is that?

Comment: Spring will set the JDBC transaction into a read-only mode and this can have an impact of the database performance. Question: how many records do you read with findServices?

Comment: there are 28k in findServices.  But in `isEpisService` there are just 5k anymore. So 5k requests to DB

Comment: So this generates thousands of SQL statements. What are you doing witth this amount of data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179192/discussion-between-patrick-and-simon-martinelli).