# Spring Boot JPA lazy fetch fails with cronjob but not controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called `Candidate` with a `OneToMany` relationship to another table:

```
/**
 * One entry for each right.
 */
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "candidate", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<AccessRight> rights;
```

This works fine with my controllers and serializing it to JSON with a mapper class.

But I now had to add a cronjob to synchronize my table with another system. There I'm getting the error:

`failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mydomain.Candidate.rights, could not initialize proxy - no Session` within my `CandidateMapper` class.

What am I missing or is different when querying my repository from a cron job?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115097/spring-data-jpa-lazy-loading-in-scheduled-and-transactional-methods or something similar. We'd need more information to find the correct duplicate or identify the exact problem.

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks that pointed me to the right direction, see me answer below

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by adding `@Transactional` to my service method that gets called from the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `@Transactional` solves the issue, but keep in mind that it will make everything happen inside a single database transaction, which might not always be desired since it can lock rows, require rollbacks if something goes wrong, etc.

Another solution is to change the fetch type to EAGER:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, ...)
```

which will have the effect that all related `AccessRight right` objects are fetched from the database at the same time as you fetch the `Candidate` object.
If you know that you will always need all the `Candidate`s, then EAGER fetching might be the best solution, since it will be faster than having to query the database sequentially for each object you encounter in your mapping function.